python tkinter - detecting arrow keys when shift and function key are pressed, or control and function key are pressed
This is a follow-on question to an earlier question
( python tkinter - detecting arrow keys when an alternate key is pressed )
I would also like to be able to detect if the function key is pressed, along with the shift, or the control key, while one of the arrow keys (up, down, left, and right) is pressed.
import tkinter

def on_key_press(event):

    if event.state & 0x0001: # shift key
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("shift and down arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            print("shift and up arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            print("shift and left arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            print("shift and right arrow")
 
    elif event.state & 0x????:     # shift key and function key 0x????
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("shift and function and down arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            print("shift and function  and up arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            print("shift and function and left arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            print("shift and function and right arrow")
 
    elif event.state & 0x0004: # control key
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("control and down arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':    
            print("control and up arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            print("control and left arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            print("control and right arrow")

    elif event.state & 0x????:    # control key and function key 0x????
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("control and function and down arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            print("control and function and up arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            print("control and function and left arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            print("control and function and right arrow")

    elif event.state & 0x20000: # alternate key
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("alternate and down arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            print("alternate and up arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            print("alternate and left arrow")
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            print("alternate and right arrow")

I'm hoping there's a pair of 0x???? masks that will make this easy.

UPDATE, following the excellent comment by Derek below.
As it happens, my Lenovo laptop has a "Fn" key on the left side of the keyboard, but this key does not work like the shift, control, or alternate keys.
Specifically, this Fn key does not generate keystrokes like "ctrl-q" or "shift-A" (for example) ... that is (for example) there is no detected key event for "Fn-q" or "Fn-A" on this keyboard.

You got an answer to your previous question. Did you try to use it for the case you're asking about here? What result did you get

I tried the former snippet, but am unsure how the function key affects the output.  I'm wondering if the function key is somehow different, that is, it doesn't seem to work in combination with shift or control.  I can't sleuth it out.

It's worth a note, I think I'll add a brief note to the original post regarding the following discovery:  my Lenovo laptop has a "Fn" key on the left side of the keyboard, between the "Ctrl" and "windows" buttons.  This "Fn" key by itself, does not register unless another key from a specific set is pressed (e.g., F1, F2, ..., F12, Home (left arrow), End (right arrow), PgUp (up arrow), PgDn (down arrow), ... and a few more).  I was misled by this key, thinking that it functioned as the shift, control, and alternate keys work, but it doesn't.

These are the event.state values from a text.bind(Key, function)
Caps lock off

262144 = 0 = "1000000000000000000" - open
262145 = 1 = "1000000000000000001" - shift
262148 = 4 = "1000000000000000100" - ctrl
262149 = 5 = "1000000000000000101" - shift+ctrl

Caps lock on

262146 = 2 = "1000000000000000010" - open
262147 = 3 = "1000000000000000011" - shift
262150 = 6 = "1000000000000000110" - ctrl
262151 = 7 = "1000000000000000111" - ctrl+shift

The following code demonstrates event behaviour and event.state values.
The equivalent binary values enable the use of bit-wise testing.
This code simply groups event.state values into tuples for testing and displays the results.
from tkinter import Tk, LabelFrame, Text

master = Tk()
frame = LabelFrame(master, text = "Report")
frame.grid(sticky = "nsew")
text = Text(frame, undo = 1)
text.grid(sticky = "nsew")

def react(event):
    if event.state in (5, 7, 262149, 262151):
        k = f"ctrl+shift keys {event.state}"
    elif event.state in (4, 6, 262148, 262150):
        k = f"ctrl key {event.state}"
    elif event.state in (1, 3, 262145, 262147):
        k = f"shift key {event.state}"
    elif event.state in (0, 2, 262144, 262146):
        k = f"open key {event.state}"
    else:
        k = f"?? {event.keysym} & {event.state} ??"
    result = f"{k} = {event.keysym}"
    frame['text'] = result
    print(result)

text.bind("<Key>", react)

text.focus_set()
master.mainloop()


Excellent help, thanks.  If I have it right, the tuples in your code refer to, in order - ( the shift ctrl or alt on the left side of the keyboard with caps unlocked, the shift ctrl or alt on the left side of the keyboard with caps locked, the shift ctrl or alt on the right side of the keyboard with caps unlocked, and the shift ctrl or alt on the right side of the keyboard with caps locked ).

Yeah pretty much and you can still use bit-wise testing.
